# can we use article before sense?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Can we use article before sense?

> There is sense of urgency in locating alternative sources of water to augment the dwindling supply.

Find error in above sentence.

Comment: Yes, we can. What makes you think that the word **"sense"** can't be preceded by an article?

Comment: Bcoz sense is an uncountable  noun..

Answer (score 1):

You must use an article before sense in this case.

There is *a* sense of urgency....